# How can I center the following content in cross browser

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, mail-form

```
#logo {
    width: 330px ;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header h1 {
    width: 760px;
    font-weight: 33px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#aboutme section {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    color: #fff;
}

section h1 {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#portfolio section {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

contact form    {
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
    width:550px;
    height:450px;
    font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding:10px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border: inset 1px solid #333;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

This is the website for the content www.swatdesignz.com it is currently undone but I would like to get the cross browser compatibility out of the way. I would always like if someone can direct me to a cross browser mail form.

Answer (score 0):

You can vertically and horizontally centre an object quite nicely using absolute positioning. The only caveat is that it has to have a fixed width and height (unless you want to calculate those dynamically using javascript).

```
.parent { position:relative; }

.item_to_be_centred { 
position:absolute;
top:50%;
height:50%;
width:100px;
height:100px;
margin:-50px 0 0 -50px;
}
```

The trick is in the negative margins being 50% of the items width/height, it tricks the browser into thinking that the elements anchor point is the dead centre instead of the top left.

**Side note:** Be careful about posting links to a site in development on a live environment. You have clearly visible PHP in the html as comments and one part of it is exposing your email address.